# hibernate one to many mapping with annotations - getting same values in the list

Tags: java, hibernate

I am Linking User table with the Application Access. Here one User can have access to many applications.
I have done the mapping successfully with the below piece of code.

User entity object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TBL", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "USER_NAME") })
public class User implements Serializable {

.....
        @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer userId;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserAppAssociation> userAssociatedApplications = new ArrayList<UserAppAssociation>();

    Getter and setter for userAssociatedApplications

}
```

Application access object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APPLICATION_ASSOC_TBL")
public class UserAppAssociation implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "application_id")
    private Integer appId;

    @Column(name = "user_type_id")
    private Integer userTypeId;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private User user;

    ..
    getters and setters

}
```

Issue:

```
I am getting the same values in the Application List ('userAssociatedApplications'). Though i have different values in the application access table, I get the same values in the list. The first row value is repeated in the list.
```

DB:

```
I have 'User' table and the mapping is with application access
```

User table: USER_TBL
Columns
user_id name phone

Application access table : APPLICATION_ASSOC_TBL

Columns
User_id application_id and User_type

Note - no primary key in this table

Sample data:
User_id application_id User_type
1       1               1
1       2               1
1       3               1

Issue: I am getting the first value 1,1,1 in the list thrice. 
Expected: List should be with 3 different values

Kindly help. I am not sure whether i am missing anyting in the annotation mapping.

Comment: what data do you have in user and application tables?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg - As i have mentioned, in the USER_TBL i have user_id, name, phone as columns with data like 1, saranya, 232323.   In the APPLICATION_ASSOC_TBL i have 3 columns User_id application_id and User_type with 2 rows 1, 1, 1 and 1,2,1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with this

```
@Id
@Column(name="user_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer userId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private User user;
```

Try to use this mapping. Please, refer this as a guide for names and don't use unnecessary annotations

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxx_users", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "f_name") })
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "f_id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserAppAssociation> applications = new ArrayList<UserAppAssociation>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name="xxx_user_applications")
public class UserAppAssociation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "f_id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_user")
    private User user;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.                                                      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_user")
    private User user;                                                                                         I tried as per your annotations , it is unsuccessful. What is the column name here "fk_user". I tried with user_id as the join column name

Comment: @Saranya It is not an annotations problem! You shouldn't use `Integer userId` in the `UserAppAssociation`. Just delete all fields and `uniqueConstraints`, except those from my example, and test. You can use `user_id` in place of `fk_user`, of course, it is just a column. But don't add two columns (`user_id`, `USER_ID`)  for the same!

Comment: @Saranya Try to recreate db schema and fill data, because of you need to have generated ids for `UserAppAssociation`.

Comment: Let me try to recreate the schema and check. But on the meantime do you mean I should have a primary key for the APPLICATION_ASSOC_TBL table? Currently i do not have any primary key for this table